# Is it Possible Publishing A Single EXE File in .net core 2.2

Tags: .net-core-2.2, .net-core-3.0

project built on .net core 2.2.want to publish single EXE file .not able to publish as single EXE file.

i tried the below command in Package console

dotnet publish -r win-x64 -c Release /p:PublishSingleFile=true

```
    Restore completed in 995.93 ms for C:\Demo\New   
    folder\BHHS\Importer\Importer.csproj.
    You are using a preview version of .NET Core. See: https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-preview
     Importer -> C:\Demo\New folder\BHHS\Importer\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.2\win-x64\Importer.dll
     C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100-preview8-013656\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Publish.targets(807,5): 
     error MSB4018: The "GenerateBundle" task failed unexpectedly.[C:\Demo\New 
 folder\BHHS\Importer\Importer.csproj] 
 C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100-preview8- 
 013656\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Publish.targets(807,5): 
     error MSB4018: 
 Microsoft.NET.HostModel.AppHost.PlaceHolderNotFoundInAppHostException: 
 Exception of type 
 'Microsoft.NET.HostModel.AppHost.PlaceHolderNotFoundInAppHostException' 
 was thrown. [C:\Demo\New folder\BHHS\Importer\Importer.csproj]
    C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100-preview8-013656\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Publish.targets(807,5): 
      error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.HostModel.AppHost.BinaryUtils.SearchAndReplace(MemoryMappedViewAccessor accessor, Byte[] searchPattern, Byte[] patternToReplace, Boolean pad0s) [C:\Demo\New folder\BHHS\Importer\Importer.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100-preview8-013656\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Publish.targets(807,5): 
     error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.HostModel.AppHost.BinaryUtils.SearchAndReplace(String filePath, Byte[] searchPattern, Byte[] patternToReplace, Boolean pad0s) [C:\Demo\New folder\BHHS\Importer\Importer.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100-preview8-013656\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Publish.targets(807,5): 
     error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.HostModel.AppHost.HostWriter.SetAsBundle(String appHostPath, Int64 bundleHeaderOffset) [C:\Demo\New folder\BHHS\Importer\Importer.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100-preview8-013656\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Publish.targets(807,5): 
     error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.HostModel.Bundle.Bundler.GenerateBundle(IReadOnlyList`1 fileSpecs) [C:\Demo\New folder\BHHS\Importer\Importer.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100-preview8-013656\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Publish.targets(807,5): 
     error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.GenerateBundle.ExecuteCore() in /_/src/Tasks/Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks/GenerateBundle.cs:line 36 [C:\Demo\New folder\BHHS\Importer\Importer.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100-preview8-013656\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Publish.targets(807,5): 
      error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.TaskBase.Execute() in /_/src/Tasks/Common/TaskBase.cs:line 38 [C:\Demo\New folder\BHHS\Importer\Importer.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100-preview8-013656\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Publish.targets(807,5): 
      error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute() [C:\Demo\New folder\BHHS\Importer\Importer.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100-preview8-013656\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Publish.targets(807,5): 
       error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost, TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext, TaskHost taskHost, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask) [C:\Demo\New folder\BHHS\Importer\Importer.csproj]
```

Answer (score 6):

No. This is possible only with .NET Core 3.0 onward. See details here - https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-core-3-0-preview-5/

There is Scott Hanselman blog post about it too - https://www.hanselman.com/blog/MakingATinyNETCore30EntirelySelfcontainedSingleExecutable.aspx